# mysql like or match for phrase

Tags: mysql, match, sql-like

I have some questions about match phrase (more than 1 word) with phrase. I have some items with keywords which I need to match.

- Case 1: the keyword is "lady's-shoes" and I need to get items with keywords "lady's-shoes lady's-shoe woman's-shoe" but not to match "lady's-jeans lady's-pants".
- Case 2: the keyword is "long dress green" and I need to get items with keywords "long dress" and "long dress green" and "long dress green for woman" but not "green shoe " nor "long dress red"

For this two cases which one do I need to use, `LIKE` or `MATCH AGAINST`? Do I need `%%` for the `LIKE`?

- Case 3: case 1 without dash (-). Is it better to find if I use dash between words? I've added dash to make sure that it's one word.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. I've edited your question to fix formatting at best I could do. Perhaps you should take some time to review those changes. While waiting for answers you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to know what you should do when someone answer to your question.

Comment: For a comment on your specific question now: "lady's-shoes" should match "woman's-shoe" but not "lady's-pants". Could you develop the "matching algorithm"? Is the word *before the dash* less relevant? How the system will know than "lady" and "woman" should be considered as synonyms? For what I see, you will probably need something *way more* sophisticated than `LIKE` of full-test search engine.

Comment: Thanks. For case 1, the "lady's-shoes" keyword should match the word "lady's-shoes" in the phrase "lady's-shoes lady's-shoe woman's-shoe". It doesn't matter if woman's-shoe is there or not.

Comment: How are the keywords "entered"? How are they "stored" (as a "phrase" or as a separate keyword table having a many-to-many relationship with the "product" table?)